# How can I avoid the generic warning

Tags: java, generics

```
public abstract class Formatter<P, R> {

    public static Object format(Object src, Class<? extends Formatter> formatter) {

        Formatter fmt;
        try {
            fmt = formatter.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return fmt.format(src);  // Unchecked call warning here
    }

    public abstract R format(P src);

}
```

How can I avoid the generic warning when invoke

```
fmt.format(src)
```

The formatter is subclass of Formatter defined like

```
PhoneFormatter extends Formatter<String, String>
```

This is the invoke code

```
if (annotation instanceof LogFormat) {
    LogFormat logFormat = (LogFormat) annotation;
    arg = Formatter.format(arg, logFormat.formatter());
}
```

-

```
public class User {

    @LogFormat(formatter = PhoneNumberFormatter.class)
    private String mobile;
}
```

I don't want to (or say I can't) use any type parameter invoke this method.

Comment: Post code as text, not as image.

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: What is the use of this method? Why are you using generics on one hand and then do this `Object`-`Object`-mapping dropping all type-safety?

Comment: @luk2302 Actually, I can't find a generic way to define the format method.

Answer (score 0):

Make the static method generic as well:

```
abstract class Formatter <P, R> {
    static <P, R> R format(P src, Class<? extends Formatter <P, R>> formatter) {
        Formatter <P, R> fmt;
        try {
            fmt = formatter.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return fmt.format(src);
    }

    abstract R format(P r);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I must take type parameters when I invoke the method. But I don't want to (or say I can't) use any type parameter when invoke this method. I add the invoke code after my question.